# Finding functions that intersect at the minimum number of points

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let $f$ and $g$ be (non-constant) functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
For a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, let us define the set $S_{f,x} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^d : f(y) = f(x) \land y \neq x \}$, and the set $S_{g,x} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^d : g(y) = g(x) \land y \neq x \}$.

Is it possible to define $f$ and $g$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d, S_{f,x} \cap S_{g,x} = \emptyset$ ? If not, then how can one define $f$ and $g$ so that (for any $x$) the number of points in $S_{f,x} \cap S_{g,x}$ is minimized ?

Comment: Take $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ to be injective. Then $S_{f,x}=\emptyset$  for all $x$. The $g$ can be any non-constant function in that case.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle Is it straightforward to find an injective function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ ? Do you have some examples (closed form expression) of such function ?

Comment: @eLearner - most functions do not have "closed form expressions". There are many injective functions from $\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R$, but they are not nice. One example that maps $(0,1)^d \to \Bbb R$ is obtained by interweaving the digits of the decimal expansions of $x_1, ..., x_n$ to form the value of $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It doesn't really matter to me if the functions aren't nice. Do you mean that e.g. for $d=3$ if the input is $< 0.01234, 0.56789423, 0.137 >$ then it should be mapped to the output $0.0511632773849423$ ? And what if the domain is $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of $(0,1)^d$ ?

Comment: Yes. That is one possible map. $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ can be easily put in 1-1 correspondence. For example, $\tan \pi\left(x-\dfrac12\right)$ does so.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok thanks. Is there any proof that the proposed function is injective ? Also, what other injective functions from $\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ do you have in mind ? (two or three other examples would be fine).

Comment: Its injectivity is obvious. Given $f(x)$, just pull the $k+nd$ digit out for each $n$ and put them together to get the decimal expansion of $x_k$. Since you can do that for each $k$, there is only one $(x_1, ..., x_d)$ that could provide that result. Other examples abound, for example choose a different base, or choose a different way of representing the $x_k$ other than by decimals (continued fractions, for example). Or compose any of those functions with any injective function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. There are uncountably many injections from $\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you. One more question: for the function $f$ consisting of interweaving the digits of the decimal expansions, do you know if it satisfies that $|x - y| < |y - z| \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < |f(y) - f(z)|$ ? where $|x - y|$ is the distance between points $x$ and $y$. If this is not satisfied, is it easy to make the injective function satisfy such a property ?

Comment: No, it does not satisfy that condition. And no, you cannot get injectivity out of continuous functions into lower dimensions..

Comment: @PaulSinclair Why does that condition imply continuity?

Comment: If it doesn't imply continuity, it comes close to it. It is a actually a very strong condition. But I'm sorry, I haven't examined this function under every random condition that you can toss out, and I do not feel particularly inclined to do so.